# Square root source code found on the net

Tags: c, algorithm, square-root

I'm looking for some algorithm for square root calculation and found this source file. I would like to try to replicate it because it seems quite simple but I can not relate it to some known algorithm (Newton, Babylon ...). Can you tell me the name?

```
int sqrt(int num) {
    int op = num;
    int res = 0;
    int one = 1 << 30; // The second-to-top bit is set: 1L<<30 for long

    // "one" starts at the highest power of four <= the argument.
    while (one > op)
        one >>= 2;

    while (one != 0) {
        if (op >= res + one) {
            op -= res + one;
            res += 2 * one;
        }
        res >>= 1;
        one >>= 2;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: It is described in [Wikipedia under "Digit-toDigit calculation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Digit-by-digit_calculation)

Comment: "Can you tell me the name?" I would call it "broke" as `sqrt(1073741824)` --> -1 rather than expected 32768.

Comment: "found this source file" --> Where?

Comment: http://www.lothar-miller.de/s9y/archives/73-Wurzel-in-VHDL.html @chux

Comment: @alukard990 The [VHDL](http://www.lothar-miller.de/s9y/archives/73-Wurzel-in-VHDL.html) version appears OK.  You may may to alert that site to the defect in the C version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [@Eugene Sh.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45148893/square-root-source-code-found-on-the-net#comment77267042_45148893) references, this is the classic "digit-by-digit" method done to calculate square root.  Learned it in [base 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Decimal_.28base_10.29) when such things were taught in primary school.

OP's code fails select numbers too.  `sqrt(1073741824) --> -1` rather than expected 32768.   `1073741824 == 0x40000000`.  Further, it fails most (all?) values this and greater.  Of course OP's `sqrt(some_negative)` is a problem too.

Candidate alternative:  also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25387376/2410359)

```
unsigned isqrt(unsigned num) {
  unsigned res = 0;
  
  // The second-to-top bit is set: 1 << 30 for 32 bits
  // Needs work to run on unusual platforms where `unsigned` has padding or odd bit width.
  unsigned bit = 1u << (sizeof(num) * CHAR_BIT - 2); 

  // "bit" starts at the highest power of four <= the argument.
  while (bit > num) {
    bit >>= 2;
  }

  while (bit > 0) {
    if (num >= res + bit) {
      num -= res + bit;
      res = (res >> 1) + bit;  // Key difference between this and OP's code
    } else {
      res >>= 1;
    }
    bit >>= 2;
  }

  return res;
}
```

---

Portability update.  The greatest power of 4 is needed.

```
#include <limits.h>
// greatest power of 4 <= a power-of-2 minus 1
#define POW4_LE_POW2M1(n) (  ((n)/2 + 1) >> ((n)%3==0)  )

unsigned bit = POW4_LE_POW2M1(UINT_MAX);
```