# While loop condition falls short

Tags: c, recursion, while-loop

So I was writing a code for a square root recursive function.
But when it came to testing the while loop would only run twice in a place it should have ran 5 times.
This is the Newton method for finding the square root.

When I pass 16 to the function the answer is 4.1 instead of 4.00. Falling short by 2 recursions.

```
float squareRoot( float n, float original )
{ 
  const float epsilon = 0.0001;
  while( abs( n*n-original) > acc)
  {
    n = squareRoot( n, original );
  }
  return n;
}
```

Comment: what is acc? It is not declared.

Comment: Try changing "float" to "double" for more accuracy.

Comment: Try `abs()` --> `fabs()`

Comment: you shouldn't be using a while loop if you're trying to do this recursively.

Comment: acc is short for accuracy, it is a global constant variable.

Comment: @jdigital, could you please elaborate?

Comment: the typical pattern for recursion is: if the end condition is reached, return the value.  otherwise recurse and return that value.  in other words, you should be using recursion in place of looping.

Comment: Alright, the issue was fixed when I used fabs(), can someone tell me the difference between them?

Comment: I dont understand how this code is working. squareRoot() function is recursively called with same "n" and "original" values. Wont it go to infinite recursion?

Comment: what arguments are you calling this with?

Comment: thought the whole point was to give a rough estimate and then let the algorithm increase the accuracy, but what is shown is a function that just returns the same n over and over again. maybe some statement left out where epsilon is used?

Comment: The issue was fixed, the code uses newton's method to find the square root. 
The arguments are the original number, and the number after I apply Newton's equation.
His method is simply take the number, divide it by two for one time and see its accuracy, which is the while loop condition. If it's not yet in the required accuracy I take the number and apply it in the equation Newton derived, google it if you require more info on the equation.

Comment: you must have entered the code incorrectly because it's pretty clear it won't work as shown.

Comment: Well, actually it's working now in the right way thanks to the fabs() function chux suggested. This is only a function from the whole code, some parts are bound to be missing, but it works anyway. Thanks all

Comment: @AhmedZeitoun I think it never entered that while loop. Put some prints and confirm once. Because, once it enters, the thread will never exit from it.

Comment: You should've post your whole code here.

Comment: Go through this page [link] (https://www.cse.wustl.edu/~kjg/cse131/Notes/SquareRoot/sqrt.html). It will help you understand what to do.

Comment: Btw. there is another Q/A [SO: Square root in C using Newton-Raphson method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038456/square-root-in-c-using-newton-raphson-method) (which I found when I was attempted to write an answer).